# Why is the dimension of the column space of a matrix $A$ equal to the dimension of the row space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The proof I have in the lecture notes is as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\dim(Im(A)) &= \#\text{ number of vectors in basis of } Im(A) \\
& =\#\text{ leading 1's in echelon matrix of }A \\
& =\#\text{ vectors in basis of }Im(A^T) \\
& =\dim(Im(A^T))
\end{align*}$$

Specifically, I have a problem following the second step, which says that the number of leading 1's in echelon matrix of $A$ is equal to the number of basis vectors for the row space $Im(A^T)$. I just cannot see where it comes from and all my attempts to prove or just understand why it is so failed.

Comment: What is the transpose of the echelon matrix?  Why must that be equivalent to the echelon matrix of the transpose?

Comment: @BettyMock The transpose of the echelon matrix is _not_ equivalent to the echelon form of the transpose. The transpose of the echelon matrix is not even in echelon form in most cases.

Comment: Have I misunderstood what the echolon matrix is? If a matrix is in upper triangular form, the transpose will be in lower triangular form.  The upper form is an arbitrary way to view things; we could as well have chosen lower triangular.